# Store a reference of an object's method received from a function

Tags: c++, methods

I was able to pass an object's non static method Dummy to another object's function. The problem comes when I try to store the reference of that method into the object of the function, I don't know how to do it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

class Dummy{
public:
    void runDummyArgs(int z){std::cout<<"TEST: "<<z<<std::endl;};
};

class Test{
public:
   
    template<typename X , typename T>
    void runTest(X* obj, T(X::* func), int z) { (obj->*func)(z); }; 
    /* It works, but I would like to store (obj->*func) in this class as a reference to reuse it when it is needed. */
};

int main()
{
    Dummy *a = new Dummy();
    Test *b = new Test();
    b->runTest(a, &Dummy::runDummyArgs, 99);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: do you want to store a pointer to that one member function or to any member function of arbitrary types?

Comment: I should be to any member function of arbitrary types, because the sender will be an unknown class.

Comment: Look into [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function). Side note: You need to tweak this example to make it sane. Uninitialized pointers suck.

Comment: And what arguments should I place in std::function?

Comment: @user4581301 Thanks. I've been able to catch it with std::function like this:
std::function<void()> action = std::bind(func, obj);
But the problem is that I need it to be declared forward, like:

std::function<void()> action; //it should go in the header
action = std::bind(func, obj); //it should go in the cpp

I don't know if I'm missing something...

Comment: In general, put non-trivial, implementation-specific details in the cpp file. My rule of thumb is if it's likely to be modified in the future, more than a few line of code long, or requires you to pull in additional headers, it should probably be separated from the class definition and implemented in a [translation unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)) where it doesn't affect anyone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write something that looks like:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

class Dummy{
public:
    void runDummyArgs(int z){std::cout<<"TEST: "<<z<<std::endl;};
};

class Test{
    std::function<void(int)> mFunc; // added member to hold function
public:
    // added constructor to accept function
    Test(std::function<void(int)> func): mFunc(func)
    {

    }
    // no longer needs any templating. It's all handled by std::function
    // most of the parameters bound by std::function 
    void runTest(int z)
    {
        mFunc(z);
    };
};

int main()
{
    Dummy a; // no need for dynamic allocation. Only use new when forced
             // and that's almost never thanks to containers and smart pointers 

    // This line gets a bit weird. I'll explain it below
    Test b([&a](int z){a.runDummyArgs(z);});

    b.runTest(99); // just needs the end argument of the function
    return 0;
}
```

OK. That's not so bad. Except for

```
Test b([&a](int z){a.runDummyArgs(z);});
```

`Test` requires a `std::function` that takes an `int` and returns nothing. `[&a](int z){a.runDummyArgs(z);}` is a [lambda expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/lambda-expressions-in-cpp?view=msvc-160) ([More documentation that gets into the niggly bits and details](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)) that defines a callable object that takes an `int` and returns nothing. The resulting instance will be called `b`. Breaking the lambda down further:

```
[&a]
```

Captures variable `a` by reference. This allows modifying `a` inside the lambda. Sometimes you want the lambda to carry around its own copy of `a`, for example if `a` is a temporary variable that won't be around when the function is called later. To stave off the common future questions about dangling references and `const Dummy` compiler errors, I'll add a simple example of capture by `mutable` value to the end of this answer.

```
(int z)
```

lambda's parameters

```
{a.runDummyArgs(z);}
```

function body that invokes `runDummyArgs` on `a`.

More complicated capture by mutable value example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

class Dummy{
    int val = 0; // provide some visible state for instances
public:
    void runDummyArgs(int z)
    {
        std::cout<<"TEST: "<<z + val << std::endl;
        //                     ^ added to show changing state
        val++; // change state
    }
};

class Test{
    std::function<void(int)> mFunc;
public:
    Test(std::function<void(int)> func): mFunc(func)
    {

    }
    void runTest(int z)
    {
        mFunc(z);
    };
};

std::function<void(int)> builder()
{
    Dummy a;
    return [a](int z)mutable{a.runDummyArgs(z);};
    //               ^ the copy of a can be modified.
} // a goes out of scope here, but its copy in the lambda lives on

int main()
{
    Test b(builder());
    b.runTest(99); // print 99
    b.runTest(99); // print 100
    Test c(builder());
    c.runTest(99); // print 99 because we have a copy of a different dummy instance
    c.runTest(99); // print 100
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thats excellent!! works perfectly, it is exactly what I needed. And the mutable value example is great also!!!
I didn't find any solution for that.....Thank you very much!!!!!!